# CKeditor with a CKFinder custom config file

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I know it is possible to load a custom config file for CKFinder

```
CKFinder.config.customConfig = baseUrl + '/js/ckfinder_config.js';
```

However, when I load CKFinder within the CKEditor I don't know how to load the custom config for CKFinder. I only got these options:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = baseUrl ;
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = baseUrl ;
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = baseUrl ;
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = baseUrl ;
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = baseUrl ;
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = baseUrl ;
}
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this API section?
http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder_2.x_api/symbols/CKFinder.config.html#.customConfig

Comment: Yes I checked this section, but it doesn't mention anything about loading a CKFinder custom config within a CKEditor

Answer (score 0):

Please see this page: http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/CKEditor_Integration#Enabling_CKFinder